# Binding to Dependency Property of Data Type Binding

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a dependency property in a custom control that is of type Binding.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Binding",
        typeof(Binding),
        typeof(CustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnDisplayMemberBindingChanged));
```

In one of my views that instantiates this custom control, I want to bind, doing the following:

```
<local:CustomControl DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SomeRandomPropertyInMyViewModel}" />
```

Obviously what I'm trying to do won't work.  So, is it possible to bind to a Dependency Property of type Binding, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want it to be of `Binding` type? Why simply not the type of `SomeRandomPropertyInMyViewModel` property? It does not have to be of `Binding` type to allow binding. It's enough that it's `DependencyProperty`. If want it to be of `Binding` type then don't declare `DependencyProperty` but normal property of `BindingBase` type for example

Comment: Thanks @dkozl, changing it from a DependencyProperty to Property solved the problem.